# git reconnect to a remote repository

Tags: git

I made a huge mistake that resulted in my having a local version of my project that is no longer connected with the remote repository it was once associated with. Is there some trick to reestablishing that connection/association w/o blowing away the local version of the code?

Comment: What exactly did you do? What are the contents of your `.git/config` file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you try:

```
git remote add --track master origin [url-to-git-repo]
```

Comment: This is not correct it attempts to create a new remote repository and results in error remote origin already exists. The OP is asking to reconnect the exiting local repo to existing remote repo

Comment: After reconnecting I had lots of merge conflicts and wanted to always accept the local version of files. I used a tip from [here](https://easyengine.io/tutorials/git/git-resolve-merge-conflicts) to do this: `grep -lr '<<<<<<<' . | xargs git checkout --ours`.