# Connecting git on new computer to previous repo

Tags: git, github

I have searched all over but can't seem to find the answer. I got a new computer, copied all my files from my previous machine over and want to reconnect to an existing repo on github.

What is the best way to do this? I cloned the directory but that actually made a subdirectory with the repo, which is what I don't want.

I just want to be able to git add files and continue like before.

Thanks

PS git status is showing all the files in my directory as untracked, even after I do git status -u no, it still displays all the untracked files.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9179161/git-reconnect-to-a-remote-repository

Comment: "I cloned the directory but that actually made a subdirectory with the repo, which is what I don't want." So why not just `cd ..` and then clone the repo? I don't see the problem here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you only copied the code files and not the `.git` directory within the project. So go to your old machine, look for the `.git` folder within the project root there and copy that as well, and that should solve it.

In case you can't do that, do the following:

- go to a fresh location in which to create the project directory `cd some/location`
- clone your existing github repo using `git clone github.com/user/project/`
- now move all your code files into this directory, overwriting existing code files.

Comment: I don't have access to my old computer, my employer replaced it.

Comment: thanks, i also had to fast forward but i think it's working now